# ALSA does not see sound cards after restoring previous HOME

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa

I have trouble with sound on a fresh installation of 12.04. I have just installed a new graphics card and with that, I decided to install 12.04 from scratch. Previously, the computer ran 11.04 and I reused the old /home partition. In 11.04 there were no issues.

I have an Audigy 2 card, which is also reflected nicely by alsa:

```
xerxes@xerxes:/proc/asound$ cat cards
 0 [Audigy2        ]: Audigy2 - SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P]
                      SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P] (rev.4, serial:0x10021102) at 0xec00, irq 16
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfe89c000 irq 45
```

However, I have no sound. If I click the sound icon in the top bar, an empty menu opens, as in this picture:

[image: Empty sound menu]

When I try to enter the sound settings (via System Settings -> Sound), the System Settings window crashes. When I try to enter the audio settings in VLC Player (via Tools -> Preferences -> Audio), VLC Player crashes. When I try to simply play music in Rhythmbox, it crashes. I cannot open pavucontrol. Alsamixer runs fine in the terminal and shows the Audigy card.

`aplay -l` outputs nothing, but `sudo aplay -l` outputs:

```
xerxes@xerxes:/proc/asound$ aplay -l
Home directory /home/xerxes not ours.
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P]], device 0: emu10k1 [ADC Capture/Standard PCM Playback]
  Subdevices: 32/32
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
  Subdevice #8: subdevice #8
  Subdevice #9: subdevice #9
  Subdevice #10: subdevice #10
  Subdevice #11: subdevice #11
  Subdevice #12: subdevice #12
  Subdevice #13: subdevice #13
  Subdevice #14: subdevice #14
  Subdevice #15: subdevice #15
  Subdevice #16: subdevice #16
  Subdevice #17: subdevice #17
  Subdevice #18: subdevice #18
  Subdevice #19: subdevice #19
  Subdevice #20: subdevice #20
  Subdevice #21: subdevice #21
  Subdevice #22: subdevice #22
  Subdevice #23: subdevice #23
  Subdevice #24: subdevice #24
  Subdevice #25: subdevice #25
  Subdevice #26: subdevice #26
  Subdevice #27: subdevice #27
  Subdevice #28: subdevice #28
  Subdevice #29: subdevice #29
  Subdevice #30: subdevice #30
  Subdevice #31: subdevice #31
card 0: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P]], device 2: emu10k1 efx [Multichannel Capture/PT Playback]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P]], device 3: emu10k1 [Multichannel Playback]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 2 Platinum [SB0240P]], device 4: p16v [p16v]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any ideas are much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the problem by upgrading my ALSA drivers as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa and, more specifically, here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Answer (score 2):

If you see your sound card with sudo:

```
sudo aplay -l
```

Then try

```
chmod -R a+rwX /dev/snd
```

Also, check your home directory for old garbage dot files from the previous installation, such as ".pulseaudio"

--Leo

Comment: I've added the output of `sudo aplay -l` to the question. I ran the `chmod` command and removed my `~/.pulse` folder, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

may your ISO be not OK. I suggest you to download it again to be sure.
Then make a DOK or disc for the installation from the "NEW" ISO.

Enter to the "LiveCD"/"Try Ubuntu without installing" and check it again.

Tell us how it gone (:

Comment: Booting a freshly downloaded ISO makes no difference, there is no sound and the same symptoms are present.