# No sound driver after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound

[image]

How to restore sound settings?

After this [ALSA does not see sound cards after restoring previous HOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177103/alsa-does-not-see-sound-cards-after-restoring-previous-home?rq=1) I start hearing mouse click but still no settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Ubuntu 17.04 does not boot when enable gdm3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906643/ubuntu-17-04-does-not-boot-when-enable-gdm3)
Sound settings return back.
Also based on this [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) I did purge all previous drivers and install most recent version. HDMI return back!